# How to create a Rails form_for with dynamic form fields from a database table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

*Sorry if this has been asked and answered in full somewhere. Not sure if I'm searching with the correct Rails speak for this question.*

I'd like to create a Rails form based on fields stored in the database.  Here's what my models looks like so far.

```
class Field < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :form
end

class Form < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :fields
end
```

The field model is very simple as of now with type:string and required:boolean columns. Name being the name of the control I'd like to create (textbox, checkbox, radiobutton).  Ideally I'd like to do something like this:

```
<%= form_for [something here] do |f| %>
  <% @fields.each do |field| %>
    <%= field.type %><br />
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I'm struggling with finding a way to replace the line <%= field.type %> with a tag that would correctly render the field.type.

Is this possible?  Would I be better off using a payload column in the field model storing field types and values as json/xml?

Comment: Is type:string storing it as the Rails method helper (like, radio_button)? In that case, you can do `f.send(field.type, field.name)`. If not, just map your type values to Rails helpers, and then you send the correct method.

Comment: Currently I'm not saving with helper methods. I'm new to the concept but it sounds exactly what I would like to do!  Would f.send() go in a tag? For example, <%= f.send(field.type, field.name) %>.  Thanks.

Comment: What @TuteC mentioned should work

Comment: you are also awesome to ask such nice question :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Like @TuteC mentioned, you can use the .send method to dynamically invoke each field, if you are saving the type:

```
<%= form_for [something here] do |f| %>
  <% @fields.each do |field| %>
    <%= f.send(field.type.to_sym, field.name) %><br />
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```